# Why doesn't my code generate random numbers without str?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me why when I remove 'str' from 7 line of code "myset.add(str(i))", do I get the same numbers every time I hit run and get random numbers with 'str' included?

```
def RandomFunction(x, y):
    myset = set()
    mylist = []
    listofnumbers = []

    for i in range(x, y):
        myset.add(str(i))
    for x in myset:
        mylist.append(int(x))

    if len(mylist) <= 5:
        print('In order to generate 5 numbers, the range of input needs to be higher')
    else:
        for y in mylist:
            listofnumbers.append(y)
            if len(listofnumbers) >= 5:
                print(listofnumbers)
                break


RandomFunction(10, 20)
```

Comment: Sets are ordered by some internal python thing that's irrelevant to you except that it's different for strings and integers. So when you put a bunch of strings in a set the order will be (sorta) random, and when you put a bunch of low value integers in a set it won't be. The order of `myset` is what gives you different results every time you run this.

Comment: A set doesn't guarantee the order of its items. It seems that for ints (or at least small ints) as set items the set is ordered but not for strings.

Comment: A `set` is not a randomizer. If you want to generate random numbers, use the `random` module.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's the catch. Don't use random function.

Comment: @Archon: If you have an assignment to generate random numbers without the `random` module, you're probably supposed to write your own RNG, and your class probably went over linear congruential generators or some other simple kind of RNG. It is very unlikely that you're supposed to search for other built-in randomization tools.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm just searching for the explanation. The code and everything works, I need to know why does it work and why doesn't it work without the str. I can't make a sense of it.

Comment: It *doesn't* work, though. Under the current CPython implementation, call this function two times in a row with the same arguments and [you'll get the same results each time](https://ideone.com/Qo12k1). "Try stuff until it looks like it works, then get someone else to explain it to you" is not an effective approach to programming.

Comment: The order in a set is sorta random for most things but not for low-value integers. That is the reason you are seeing it change the order with str. The other comments that this is not a working way to make random numbers are entirely correct.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It works for what I need. I won't call two same functions. I have my own approach to programming. Thank you.

Comment: A real random number generator has the ability to generate the same number more than once. Your function doesn't (in addition to other problems). I wouldn't expect a passing grade on this.

Comment: @CJR Yes, a 'real' one has. This is probably a joke of a code but I am still a beginner so this is expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set keeps the elements in hash table, it uses default python's `hash()` function. Its implementation for numeric types looks like this:

```
def hash(number):
    return number % (2 ** 61 - 1)
```

So, if the numbers aren't huge, hash value of an integer will be equal to the same integer. Because of this integers in python's set will be kept in ascending order (`for` also reads hash table in ascending order).

But string is a sequense of unicode characters with `\0` at the end and python has another implementation of `hash()` for strings, so it won't work the same way for them.